# Begonia leaf problems

Tags: trees, diagnosis, leaves

We live in southern Spain and have had a begonia ricosoleana growing up the side of the house for two years without problems. We are south facing.  However, this year we had white and black fly and we have treated this with a spray for the whitefly and the old remedy of fairy liquid for the black fly. I have now hosed the whole plant thoroughly. But the leaves are 'folded in half ' along the main spine. What is causing this and is there anything I can do?

Comment: Can you add a photograph or two please, or a full description of the plant - I am unable to find any plant called Begonia ricosoleana - I can find a Podranea ricosoliana (pink trumpet vine) but first we need to establish precisely  which plant you have. Photo will help with identifying  its problem too